# how to export values after each loop to excel file in GAMS

Tags: excel, optimization, export-to-excel, gams-math

I want to know how to export values after each loop to an Excel file in GAMS
EX: Calculate the sum from 1 to 5

```
Scalar itrlim upper limit of the summation /5/
        k summation variable
        S value of summation /0/;
        
for(k=1 to itrlim by 1,
S=S+k
);

display S;
```

| k | S |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 6 |
| 4 | 10 |
| 5 | 15 |

I have tried the commands execute_unload + execute, but the result is not as expected.

Comment: (1) Use the put statement to write values in each iteration to a CSV file. PUT has tools to help write CSV formatted files. (2) Collect data in a single PARAMETER and then export the parameter to a GDX file and call GDXXRW to move this into an XLSX file. This is  easier when looping over a set instead of a scalar.